# How do I delete one character from a string at a time?

Tags: c++, string, loops

I am trying to figure out how to delete one character at a time from a string, so that I can obtain all versions of the string with only one character missing at a time. This is what I am trying to make work, but to no avail.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++){
    tmp.erase(0, i);
    std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
    s.at(i)++;
}
```

It obviously works correctly for the first one, but then deletes the rest.
JON should have an expected output of ON JN JO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a copy of the string each time, and modify the copy:

```
for(std::string::size_type i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++){
    auto tmp=copy;
    tmp.erase(i, 1);
    std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
}
```

For correctness, the index variable should be a `std::string::size_type`, what both `length()` and `size()` return (with `size_t` and `size()` naturally belonging together).

Your code almost got it right, except that it neglected to make the copy of the string each time, and `s.at(i)++` didn't belong there.

Comment: For *correctness*, the index should be `std::string::size_type`, which may or may not be `size_t`.  Also, `tmp.erase(i)` will erase all characters from the specified index until the end of the string. To erase just a single character, you need to use `tmp.erase(i, 1)` or `tmp.erase(tmp.begin()+i)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah that makes a lot of sense! Thank you. Lol smh at the s.at(i)++...

Answer (score 3):

You are not resetting `tmp` to the original string value on each loop iteration, so it keeps erasing more and more characters from `tmp` until it is empty.

You are also removing the wrong range of characters on each loop iteration.

You are also modifying the *original* string on each loop iteration to increment the value of its individual characters.  Why are you doing that at all?

Try something more like this instead:

```
for(std::string::size_type i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++){
    std::string tmp = s;
    tmp.erase(i, 1);
    std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with iterators and temp copies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s("abcdefg");
    for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    {
        const std::string b = { s.begin(), i }; // temp copy!
        const std::string e = { i + 1, s.end() }; // temp copy!
        std::cout << b << e << '\n';
    }
}
```

A solution without temporary copies, C++20 [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
int main()
{
    std::string s("abcdefg");
    for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    {
        const std::string_view b = { s.begin(), i };
        const std::string_view e = { i + 1, s.end() };
        std::cout << b << e << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
bcdefg
acdefg
abdefg
abcefg
abcdfg
abcdeg
abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one simple and straight:

```
while (TMP.size()) {
    cout << TMP << '\n';
    TMP.erase(0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's all damn inefficient.

Just make a copy without the last character, and then slowly, iteration by iteration, replace the end of that copy with characters from the original.

```
template <class F>
void do_with_one_missing(std::string_view s, F f) {
    auto i = size(s);
    if (i-- > 0) return;
    std::string x = s.remove_suffix(1);
    f(std::as_const(x));
    while (i-- > 0) {
        x[i] = x[i + 1];
        f(std::as_const(x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        string s1=s;
        s1.erase(i,1);
        cout<<s1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add an explanation, why this code is working or why it is different to the other answers.